# Display total reputation earned by accepted answers upvotes

Tags: support, reputation, search

Need a search query for total reputation earnings of a given user by category

Ex:

```
 Total #   Sum                   Category
    5      5X5   = 25            Question upvoted
    5      5x-2  = -10           Question downvoted
    5      5x-2  = -10           Answer downvoted
    5      5x10  = 50            Answer upvoted  
    5      5x15  = 75            Answer accepted   
    5      5x2   = 10            Useful edits
    5      5X2 = 10              I accepted answer for my question
    5      5x-1 = -5             I voted down on a question/answer
```

---

Edit:

This link https://stackoverflow.com/reputation provided details but there is no aggregation. i.e how many total question/answer/downvote etc.

Comment: For yourself, you can [analyse the output of http://stackoverflow.com/reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation/43005#43005).